# What does P.E.K.K.A stand for?

Tags: clash-of-clans, terminology, clash-royale

For what does P.E.K.K.A stand in the names of the massive destruction troops "Mini P.E.K.K.A" and "P.E.K.K.A"?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

From the [Clash of Clans wiki](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/P.E.K.K.A):

> The letters in P.E.K.K.A don't officially stand for anything in
> particular. Supercell held a [Facebook contest](https://www.facebook.com/ClashofClans/photos/478339952190333) on 22 August 2012 to see
> who could come up with the best written-out name for P.E.K.K.A as
> judged by the number of likes the comment received. The name "Perfect
> Enraged Knight Killer of Assassins" was the winner.

In addition to this, "Pekka" is a popular given name in Finland, where Supercell (developer of *Clash of Clans* and *Clash Royale*) is from. (Thanks to user @Jeffery Lebowski for pointing this out).

Comment: I'd add that the phony acronym pun is that Pekka is a popular Finnish given name (e.g. Pekka Kokko is Kalmah's frontman), and Supercell (Clash of Clans and Clash Royale developers) is a Finnish company.